# Can I get Access token of any twitter accounter by just passing user name and password

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, access-token

I want to get twitter access token by just passing twitter user name and password.
Is there any way to get this?

Help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Twitter provides [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/xauth) which allows you to submit a username and password, then get back your tokens.

Please note, there are two main restrictions.

1. You won't get DM access.
2. You need to specifically request xAuth access from Twitter

> xAuth access is restricted to approved applications. If your application is a desktop or mobile application that has no other recourse but to utilize xAuth, send a detailed request to https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

I would strongly suggest that you find a way to incorporate the normal oAuth flow into your app.